# QGIS how to know which ids are used in (All layers)

Tags: qgis, wms, layers

I've connecting to my provider WMS, but the problem I face is I want to know which layers and in which order they are setup in the (All Lager (All layers))

When I choose it, the layer panel shows one group layer named (All layers) but I can't see the ids of the layers inside it.

When I look through the network request it sends, inside the layer parameter `show:` is provided. But that works only on the `export`feature and not for the `WMS service`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the GetCapabilities URL of that service?

Comment: @user30184 sure thing: `https://arcgis.icebound.com/arcgisserversite/services/FollowITLafayette/NorgeLight/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS`

Comment: The URL does not work for me.

Comment: Is it the `GetCapabilities.xml`you trying to read? If so, i can paste the content in pastebin

Comment: The response of the GetCapabilities response, yes.

Comment: @user30184 here you go: https://pastebin.com/RYfHDt9V

I got it sent by email from the provider. Appericate that you are taking your time :)

Comment: The GetCapabilities response gives you the layer identifiers (Name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit hard to give a short answer. I fear I must suggest reading the WMS standard http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=14416 together with the GetCapabilities document. However, I can give some advice about how to start.

In WMS layers have names and titles. Name is a technical name that is used for communicating with servers. Titles are for human beings.

If a layer has only a title but no name it is used as a bookmark. WMS clients can build a nicer layer menu with those titles.

> A Title is mandatory for all layers; it is a human-readable string for
> presentation in a menu. The Title is not inherited by child Layers.
>
> If, and only if, a layer has a Name, then it is a map layer that can
> be requested by using that Name in the LAYERS parameter of a GetMap
> request. A Layer that contains a  element is referred to as a
> “named layer” in this International Standard. If the layer has a Title
> but no Name, then that layer is only a category title for all the
> layers nested within. A server that advertises a Layer containing a
> Name element shall be able to accept that Name as the value of LAYERS
> argument in a GetMap request and return the corresponding map. A
> client shall not attempt to request a layer that has a Title but no
> Name.

Examples from the beginning of GetCapabilities:

This is a top level Title of the service:

```
<Layer>
<Title>
<![CDATA[ PublishNorgeLight ]]></Title>
```

Underneath there is a new group, still without a name

```
<Layer queryable="1">
<Title>
<![CDATA[ FKB_7000 ]]></Title>
```

That is followed by the first named layer. It belongs to the group "FBK_7000" The name of the layer is "1"

```
<Layer queryable="1">
<Name>1</Name>
<Title>
<![CDATA[ fkb_ar5_omrade ]]></Title>
```

The total number of the layers in that WMS is 144. If I count right, 136 of those are named layers, and the rest have just titles.

I cannot find the text "Alla lager" from the GetCapabilities so I guess that QGIS is changing the name of the title of the service "PublishNorgeLight" into "all layers".

[image]

As an answer to your question I would say that "Alla lager" contains all the layers in the service which have names. However, "Alla leger" cannot be connected directly but the WMS client must create a list of all the layer names underneath it in the layer tree. The order of the layers will the same than in the GetCapabities. It means that layer=1 will be rendered first, layer=2 on top of that and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and taking your time. Now i have a better understanding what is happening